# select to drop and keep some variables in same select call

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to both drop and reorder some features in a data frame in the same `select()` call if possible. As opposed to `select(-var_to_drop) %>% select(var_I_want_first, everything())` can this be done in the same call?

E.g. with the diamonds dataset, suppose I want to drop the carat field, make price the first field and then keep everything() after that in it's same order? Tried:

```
library(tidyverse)
diamonds %>% select(-carat, price, everything()) # keeps carat
diamonds %>% select_at(vars(-carat, price, everything())) # also keeps carat?
```

Desired outcome is:

```
# desired outcome with multiple select() calls, want to do it in one:
diamonds %>% select(-carat) %>% select_at(vars(price, everything()))
# A tibble: 53,940 x 9
   price cut       color clarity depth table     x     y     z
   <int> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1   326 Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55  3.95  3.98  2.43
 2   326 Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61  3.89  3.84  2.31
 3   327 Good      E     VS1      56.9    65  4.05  4.07  2.31
 4   334 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58  4.2   4.23  2.63
 5   335 Good      J     SI2      63.3    58  4.34  4.35  2.75
 6   336 Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57  3.94  3.96  2.48
 7   336 Very Good I     VVS1     62.3    57  3.95  3.98  2.47
 8   337 Very Good H     SI1      61.9    55  4.07  4.11  2.53
 9   337 Fair      E     VS2      65.1    61  3.87  3.78  2.49
10   338 Very Good H     VS1      59.4    61  4     4.05  2.39
```

Can I get my desired result in a single call to select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can specify the columns to be removed after `everything()`

```
library(dplyr)
diamonds %>% 
     select(price, everything(), -carat)
```